# pip install tweepy on mac is not working

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

These are the versions that I am working with

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.10
$ pip --version 
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Ideally I should be able to install tweepy. But that is not happening.

```
$ pip install tweepy 
Collecting tweepy
  Using cached tweepy-3.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six>=1.7.3 (from tweepy)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.4.3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tweepy)
Requirement already satisfied: oauthlib>=0.6.2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.4.1->tweepy)
Installing collected packages: six, tweepy
  Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling six-1.4.1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
```

A bunch of lines deleted for brevity. It finally ends at ...

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-CBvMLu-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Can anyone help?

**Update** Tried the following as well. But did not solve the problem

```
$ sudo -H pip install tweepy
```

Answer (score 1):

Install it with:

```
sudo pip install tweepy
```

Looks like a permission problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. The way I solved it was to download python 2.7.13 from the official website and install it. After that, I installed pip with:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

And after that:

```
pip install tweepy
```

Hope it is still relevant :)